# Calling main method within the class python

Tags: python, program-entry-point

I am trying to execute my program from Main method. I have tried it call 
RandomPrograms.main() as well as simply main() but nothing works.

I also tried to make the main method static but it too does not works.

Error I am currently getting is

> No value for argument 'self' in unbound method call

```
class RandomPrograms:
def __init__(self):
    pass

def func1(self):
  new_dic={}
  dlist=[]
  for x in range(0,3):
     new_dic["data{}".format(x)]=x
  dlist.append(new_dic.copy())
  print (dlist)  

def main(self):       
  abc=RandomPrograms()
  abc.func1() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
  RandomPrograms.main()
```

Comment: Your identation is wrong. Please correct it so that it is exactly like in your real code. As it is, we can't know if you made `main` a method of your class or a function.

Comment: You could look into the decorator `@classmethod`, but I don't see the motivation for this sort of code. It almost seems like you are trying to write Java-style code inside of Python (and [Python is not Java](https://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html)).

Comment: Your class is useless. Remove it and your code will work.

Comment: Hi there! You should inform the `self`, for our luck it's informed automatically, but you have to inform the way how it is going to be passed, how can you do it?! You just have to use the parentese, `RandomPrograms().main()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you don't need a class.
However you could do something like this:

```
class RandomPrograms:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func1(self):
        new_dic={}
        dlist=[]
        for x in range(0,3):
            new_dic["data{}".format(x)]=x
        dlist.append(new_dic.copy())
        print (dlist)  

    @staticmethod
    def main():       
        abc=RandomPrograms()
        abc.func1() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    RandomPrograms.main()
```

or

```
class RandomPrograms:

    def __init__(self):
        self.func1()

    def func1(self):
        new_dic={}
        dlist=[]
        for x in range(3):
            new_dic[f"data{x}"]=x
        dlist.append(new_dic)
        print(dlist)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    RandomPrograms()
```

Read about how to properly define classes [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html)